# How to format pySerial output better?

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm just learning python and am using it to grab serial data from a device using the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial, string
import time

output = " "
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, 8, 'N', 1, timeout=1)

while True:
  print ("----")
  while output != "":
    output = ser.readline()
    print (output)
  output = " "
```

the serial string returned is:

`b'C123b,117,126,061,0799,0\r\n'`

Could somebody point me in the direction of some resource for how I could learn to format this output better in e.g:

```
Mode: C
Version: 1.23
Steam Temperature: 117
Steam Target Temp: 126
Group Temp: 96°
Heating Timer: 13 minutes
Heating Element: Off
```

Comment:  Domje :) You might find the function called str.split pretty interesting: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: What happened to the `b` is `C123b`?

Comment: `061` hexadecimal is 97 not 96 in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want requires parsing the serial data being read. Here's one way to do it. I had to guess on the data format of several of the fields because you didn't specify what is was in your question. If any were wrong, you should be able to easily fix them. I find it strange that some numeric fields appear to be in hexadecimal, but others are decimal.

```
fields = ('Mode', 'Version', 'Steam_Temperature', 'Steam_Target_Temp', 'Group_Temp',
          'Heating_Timer', 'Heating_Element')

output = b'C123b,117,126,061,0799,0\r\n'
data = output.decode().strip().split(',')  # Separate comma-delimited fields.
mode, ver = data[0][0], data[0][1:-1]  # Separate undelimited subfields.
data = [mode, ver] + data[1:]  # Replace original with separated subfields.

data_dict = dict(zip(fields, data))
#print(f'{data_dict=}')
# Convert values is certain fields.
data_dict['Version'] = format(float(data_dict['Version'])/100, '.2f')
data_dict['Group_Temp'] = int(data_dict['Group_Temp'], 16)  # Convert to decimal.
data_dict['Heating_Timer'] = int(data_dict['Heating_Timer']) // 60  # Convert to minutes.
data_dict['Heating_Element'] = ('On' if int(data_dict['Heating_Element']) else
                                'Off')  # Convert to boolean, then string.

print('''\
Mode: {Mode}
Version: {Version}
Steam Temperature: {Steam_Temperature}
Steam Target Temp: {Steam_Target_Temp}
Group Temp: {Group_Temp}°
Heating Timer: {Heating_Timer} minutes
Heating Element: {Heating_Element}\
'''.format(**data_dict))
```